# Best way to index very long filepaths in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, database-design

Given the following filepaths, stored in a mysql database:

```
.//.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
.//.git/refs/tags
.//__init__.py
.//__init__.pyc
.//forms.py
.//forms.pyc
.//models.py
.//models.pyc
.//settings.py
.//settings.pyc
.//static
.//static/css
.//static/css/all.css
.//static/images
.//static/images/bg.png
.//static/images/favicon.ico
.//static/images/pds-header-logo.png
.//static/images/pds-logo.png
.//static/images/revolver.png
.//static/js
.//static/js/all.js
.//templates
.//templates/base.html
.//templates/default.html
.//templates/overview.html
.//urls.py
.//urls.pyc
.//views.py
.//views.pyc
.//wsgi.py
.//wsgi.pyc
```

Someone needs to be able to search the path. For example if the user searched for "static", it would return the results with "static " in the path:

```
.//static
.//static/css
.//static/css/all.css
.//static/images
.//static/images/bg.png
.//static/images/favicon.ico
.//static/images/pds-header-logo.png
.//static/images/pds-logo.png
.//static/images/revolver.png
.//static/js
.//static/js/all.js
```

The search that I currently have is something like:

```
`SELECT path FROM files WHERE path LIKE '%search%';`
```

Is there a way to index this column / improve this search (remove the LIKE %%), as I probably have 1M+ filepaths on this system. Note that the filepath could be 200+ characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Wildcard search won't make use of index.
If you index the file path, you can only best support queries like

```
/static/images/%
```

Given your scenario, if you want to to allow wildcard search,
your best bet is to explode the directory to become multiple keywords:

```
static
images
revolver
.png
```

Then store each of the keyword into a keyword table,
and build the relationship.

When you perform the wildcard search is actually search the keyword table.

Comment: Good idea with this approach. I'll try it non-indexed and if that is too slow I'll use your split/keyword approach.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could actually have a "index of partial names". Something like this:

```
id ! name    ! parent
---------------------
1  ! static  ! 0           // at root. 
2  ! css     ! 1           // Parent is "static"
3  ! all.css ! 2           // parent is css
4  ! images  ! 1           // parent is static
5  ! bg.png  ! 4           // images.
```

It will need a bit of work to read out the original filename, unless you store that as well.